# Given $P(X=0)=1-\frac1{a^2}$ and $P(X=a)=P(X=-a)\frac1{2a^2}$, compute $P(|X| \geq a)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Given is random variable 
>   $X:\begin{pmatrix}-a&0&a\\\frac{1}{2a^2}&1-\frac{1}{a^2}&\frac{1}{2a^2}\end{pmatrix}$.
>   Calculate $P(|X| \geq a)$

I'm not sure how to do this correct? But that notation reminds me very much of *Markov's inequality* which says in general that 
$$P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}$$

So I would start by calculating the expected value of our given random variable $|X|$:

$$E(|X|) = \frac{1}{2a^2} \cdot |-a| + \left(1-\frac{1}{a^2}\right) \cdot |0| + \frac{1}{2a^2} \cdot |a| = \frac{|-a|}{2a^2}+0+\frac{|a|}{2a^2} = \frac{a}{2a^2}+\frac{a}{2a^2} = \frac{1}{a}$$

So we have that 
$$P(|X| \geq a) \leq \frac{\frac{1}{a}}{a} \Leftrightarrow P(|X| \geq a) \leq \frac{1}{a^2}$$

Is it really correct like that? I need to know it please because I would do it like that in the exam too? :s

Comment: You better don't do it like that in the exam. You are making things more difficult than they are and also your end result is not okay.

Comment: @drhab Thank you I try to find another, similar example and do it, and see if it's good with your answers and hints you all gave me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the fact that $\frac1{2a^2}$ shows up in your question we conclude that $a\neq0$. Now we discern in this context two cases:

- $a<0$ then $P(|X|\geq a)=1$
- $a>0$ then $P(|X|\geq a)=P(|X|\neq0)=\frac1{a^2}$

The first is based on the fact that $|X|$ is a non-negative random variable so that $P(|X|\geq a)=1$ for every $a<0$.

The second is based on the data in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Markov's inequality only gives you an (unsharp) *upper bound*.  The question asks for a *value*.

$$\begin{aligned}
P(|X|\ge a) &= P(X = a) + P(X = -a) \\
&= \frac{1}{2a^2} + \frac{1}{2a^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{a^2}
\end{aligned}$$

---

Edit in response to drhab's comment.

If $a < 0$, the event $\{|X| \ge a\} = \{|X| \ge 0\}$ is always realised, so $P(|X| \ge a) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand all, how do you know we don't need $P(X=0)$ as well?

Comment: As you write $\frac{1}{2a^2}$ in the question, I suppose $a \ne 0$.  $\{|X| \ge a \text{ and } X = 0\} \subseteq \{ 0 \ge a \} = \varnothing$

Comment: And what if $a<0$?

Comment: @drhab I see your point, and I edited my answer in response to your comment.  I *guess* OP missed it as he/she wrote $E[|X|] = \cdots = \frac1a$